# Difference Between Nombro and Numero

Tags: word-difference

In English we simple say number for quantity and for the physical number. What is the difference between nombro and numero?

Answer (score 4):

> Nombro = number, amount. Hence: nombri = (1) “to count,” (2) “to be at
> the quantity of.” Not to be confused with:
>
> numero = (1) copy, edition (of a magazine); (2) number, digit, cipher. Hence: numeri = “to number, put numbers on.” (Some speakers use the still unusual term diĝito = “digit,” especially in technical
> contexts.)
>
> numeralo = numeral.
>
> numeratoro = numerator.
>
> cifero = number, written sign for a number.

[http://pages.ucsd.edu/~dkjordan/eo/colloq/colloq190.html#nombro](http://pages.ucsd.edu/%7Edkjordan/eo/colloq/colloq190.html#nombro)